# Cross Browser File Upload Input Hack

Tags: jquery, css, forms, file-upload

I am using a hack to make the file input appear consistent across all browsers. I am using [this technique](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html). Basically, you set the opacity of the file upload input to 0, and absolutely position it above another input that is styled (for cross browser consistency). When the user clicks on the "File Upload" area they are really clicking the input below it, but because the opacity of the upload area is zero, it still triggers the upload dialog box. This hack works very well (read more in the link), however, there is one main issue: Because the opacity is set to 0, you dont see the file path, which is necessary to let the user know that the browse button worked.

I am looking for a jquery solution that does the following: When a user browses for a file, jquery will store the filename / path in a variable, and then display that variable as another input's (previous input) value. That said, when a user selects a file, the file name is displayed in the other input as a value.

Here is my HTML / CSS:

```
<div id="upload">
    <input type="text" id="fakeUpload" value="Choose File">
    <span class="file-upload">
        <input type="file" name="file-upload" class="wpcf7-file" size="1" value="1">
    </span>
</div>


#upload{position:relative; float:left; width:100%; cursor:pointer;}
#upload input#fakeUpload{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; display:block; font-size:15px; color:black; background:#f1f1f1; padding:7px 5%;  width:90%!important; cursor:pointer; z-index:1;}
#career input[type="file"] {opacity: 0; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:2; text-align: right;}
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: It's a security issue to display the path of the file but you can get the actual file name with `$('.wpcf7-file').on('change', function(){ this.value });`

Comment: on the link I provided, they do it with plan javascript

Comment: yes the actual file name is finem, it doesnt need to be the path

Comment: @AdamMerrifield can you structure it in a question, also storing the value in a variable so I can test and accept it?

Comment: You know, the post you are referencing completely defeats its own purpose at the end.  You are just going to route the click event, right?

Comment: yes, but it works with contact form 7 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
$('.wpcf7-file').on('change', function(){
    $('#fakeUpload').val(this.value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fEp68/

The demo doesn't have your styling, but you can use your imagination :]

Comment: this is great, thanks! Chrome displays the full path, and its not working in firefox, but I will debug that.

Comment: It's working fine for me in FF 12. What is your current version.

Comment: Also 12...my problem isnt with your code, but rather my original code. It looks like  even though the invisible input has a z-index of 2, it isnt clickable...

Comment: It works to the right of the input, but where the value is, it just clicks on the value not the invisible input

Answer (score 1):

Don't depend only in the opacity for the click. If the user is using a browser that have a inconsistent display (such as mobile browser), the file input may not be exactly above the "fake" input, so he will not be able to click it

Here is an equivalent solution, but depends on javascript to click on the real input:
html. Note that the "real" input is not hidden, , but you can apply a `display:none` to it:

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QPUJa/

html:

```
normal file:<input type="file" name="myfile" id="myfile" />
<br /> <br /> 
Fake: <input type="text" id="choosebox" />
<a href="#" id="choose">Choose</a>
```

js:

```
$("#choose").click(function(){
    $("#myfile").click();
    return false;
});

$("#myfile").change(function(){
    $("#choosebox").val($(this).val())
});
```

Based on that, it's kinda easy to create a script that automatically finds all input files and replace with fake files on page load.